# How can I get constants and specific instances of Uninterpreted sort under Z3 Solver/theorem prover?

Tags: z3, z3py, theorem-proving

```
x_instance = IntVal('3')
x_uninterpred_const1 = Const("x",IntSort())
x_uninterpred_const2 = Int("x")# syntax sugar for the former line above
```

In Z3, we use the term "variable" for universal and existential variables. Quantifier-free formulas do not contain variables, only constants. But at least we can get an int_instance with the value three at the same time.

Then when I use Z3 for Blockworld, I have found this:

```
BlockType, (block1,block2) = EnumSort('Block', ('block1','block2'))
x, y, z, w = Consts('x y z w', BlockType)
```

I think this means, constants "x, y, z, w" can be either block1 or block2, it depends on what constraint we set for the next `Solver().add()`, but now  I want constants "x, y, z, w" to be countless blocks even I have not "Enum" all possible block instance like "A, B, C, D,..." yet.

But now I just have two specific block instance name "block1,block2". How can I get this in Z3 solver? (Just like the IntVal("3") and IntSort constant above)

I wrote the code below, but I don't think it is right:

```
BlockType = DeclareSort('Block type')#Uninterpreted or free Sorts"BlockType", 
block1, block2 = Consts('blockinstance1 blockinstance2',BlockType) #this seems wrong but I do not know how to write. #I do not how to get this: I want two specific block but not constants(a.k.a variables of BlockType)
x, y, z, w = Consts('x y z w', BlockType) # constants(a.k.a variables of BlockType)
```

Answer (score 1):

It's not quite clear to me what exactly you're asking, but it appears you want to have an enum constant that's always fixed at one value? (Akin to what `IntVal` does for integers.)

To do so, simply assert the equality in the solver:

```py
from z3 import *

BlockType, (block1,block2) = EnumSort('Block', ('block1', 'block2'))

s = Solver()
x = Const('x', BlockType)
s.add(x == block1)
print(s.check())
print(s.model())
```

This prints:

```
sat
[x = block1]
```